# CSS Bootstrap Panel Gaps - Make like Pinterest

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pinterest

I have some div panels, and after each one there is a gap on the left, when the column on the right is bigger than the last.

How can I make it come under each one (like pinterest)

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jamesinger/5sg29v58/2/)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class=" panel">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h4>First Cell</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class=" panel">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h4>Second Cell</h4>
         <h4>Second Cell</h4>
         <h4>Second Cell</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class=" panel">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h4>Third Cell</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class=" panel">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h4>Third Cell</h4>
         <h4>Third Cell</h4>
         <h4>Third Cell</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class=" panel">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h4>Third Cell</h4>
         <h4>Third Cell</h4>
         <h4>Third Cell</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want could you elaborate bit more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it (like Pinterest) in another way like this:

[**JsFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/sdg4xohv/)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}


.row {
 -moz-column-width: 18em;
 -webkit-column-width: 18em;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-gap:1em; 
  
}

.item {
 display: inline-block;
 padding:  .25rem;
 width:  100%; 
}

.well {
 position:relative;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="item">
         <div class="well">
            <h4>First Cell</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="well">
            <h4>Second Cell</h4>
            <h4>Second Cell</h4>
            <h4>Second Cell</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="well">
            <h4>Third Cell</h4>
            <h4>Third Cell</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="well">
            <h4>Third Cell</h4>
            <h4>Third Cell</h4>
            <h4>Third Cell</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="well">
            <h4>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid laudantium veritatis expedita optio aperiam modi, odit eius
            </h4>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="well">
            <h4>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            </h4>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes iv'e seen that one but I need to use the same classes, as when i use the above, it distorts my entire page.

Comment: OK sory - i didn't see the row class - renamed it and all is good - cheers

Comment: Question - how do I make it always do 2 columns unless down to a certain size - all above just 2 columns ?

Comment: Defaulting to 3 columns when on large resolution